# Find a stored fingerprint using Free FingerPrint Verification SDK

Tags: c#, fingerprint

I've been modifying the code that the SDK provides. The code give me an option to verify the scanned fingerprint with the one selected in a ItemList, and returns a value of the calculated score, and says if the scanned fingerprint is the same as the selected. But what I want is to read the fingerprint and find it in the database. I'm using a U.are.U 4500 Fingerprint Reader. So what I want to do is this, I want to perform is a `matching one-to-many`

So, here's the code before modification that do the match:

```
    private void btnVerify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lbDatabase.SelectedIndex < 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a record from the database.");
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs taskResult = BusyForm.RunLongTask("Waiting for fingerprint ...", new DoWorkEventHandler(doVerify),
                    false, ((CData)lbDatabase.SelectedItem).EngineUser, new EventHandler(CancelScanningHandler));
                VerificationResult verificationResult = (VerificationResult)taskResult.Result;
                if (verificationResult.engineStatus == NffvStatus.TemplateCreated)
                {
                    if (verificationResult.score > 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} verified.\r\nFingerprints match. Score: {1}", ((CData)lbDatabase.SelectedItem).Name, verificationResult.score));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} not verified.\r\nFingerprints do not match. Score: {1}", ((CData)lbDatabase.SelectedItem).Name, verificationResult.score));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Verification was not finished. Reason: {0}", verificationResult.engineStatus));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    private void doVerify(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs args)
    {
        VerificationResult verificationResult = new VerificationResult();

        verificationResult.score = _engine.Verify((NffvUser)args.Argument, 20000, out verificationResult.engineStatus);
        args.Result = verificationResult;
    }
```

and here is the code with the modifications I made to find the fingerprint in the database.

```
     private void btnVerify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            try
            {

                RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs taskResult = BusyForm.RunLongTask("Waiting for finger ...", new DoWorkEventHandler(doVerify),
                    false, lbDatabase.Items.Cast<CData>().ToArray(), new EventHandler(CancelScanningHandler));
              VerificationResult verificationResult = (VerificationResult)taskResult.Result;

                if (verificationResult.engineStatus == NffvStatus.TemplateCreated)
                {
                    if (verificationResult.score > 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} verified.\r\nFingerprints match. Score: {1}", ((CData)lbDatabase.SelectedItem).Name, verificationResult.score));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} not verified.\r\nFingerprints do not match. Score: {1}", ((CData)lbDatabase.SelectedItem).Name, verificationResult.score));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Verification was not finished. Reason: {0}", verificationResult.engineStatus));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

    }

    private void doVerify(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs args)
    {
        CData[] items = (CData[])args.Argument;
        VerificationResult verificationResult = new VerificationResult();

        uint timep = 5000;
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i != 0)
            {
                timep = 0;
            }
            verificationResult.score = _engine.Verify(items[i].EngineUser, timep, out verificationResult.engineStatus);
            if (verificationResult.score > 0) break;
        }
        args.Result = verificationResult;
    }
```

Well, when I scan the persons finger and is the first one in the database I get the correct result (the score of the match), but when the scanned finger is in another place that is not the first one in the itemList the `verificationResult.score` always retuns a `-1`.
I don't know if this implementation is correct I would like any suggest.

Comment: whats the value of verification.engine status?

Comment: verifcation.engine status is used when there was a scanned finger in other way it returns that the verication didn't finish because it wasn't scanned any finger in the time of waiting

Comment: @user2461687 have you resolved this? i having the same issue.